# Why should Android data be committed/read in onPause() - onResume() rather than in onStop() - onStart()?

Tags: android, android-activity

The documentation suggests that the data should be committed/read in `onPause()`/`onResume()`.

Yet when the application is no longer in the foreground, its data structures remain intact, which suggests that one could delay committing/reading data until the application is no longer visible, i.e. in `onStop()`/`onStart()`. Particularly since `onStop()` is guaranteed to be called before `onDestroy()`.

Is it perhaps the case that either approach is suitable? Is the documentation giving here merely a guideline?

**Update**
Suppose your application needed to save relatively substantial data, say edits to a large image. One would then surely *not* write/read in `onPause()`/`onResume()`, lest the user experience become sluggish. One would in that case choose instead to write/read in `onStop()`/`onStart()`. Is that true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with using `onStop` is that you have no guarantees on when it will be called since the only sure thing is that it will be called before `onDestroy`. If you wait until `onStop` to commit your data it may be to late for another activity to show/use any of those changes. Same thing applies to `onStart`, your activity may not need to be restarted if it was just in the background so you'll have stale data. Using `onResume` and `onPause` guarantees that your data will always be current, commits are made as soon as the activity goes to the background and new data is loaded as soon as it becomes visible.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Let me rephrase it to make sure I understand. If the application consists of a single activity, then it is perfectly suitable to use either the visible cycle or the foreground cycle for reading/writing. If the application consists instead of two or more activities that will read each other's data, it becomes necessary to use the visible cycle. For every other scenario, the programmer is free to choose—it makes no difference. Do you agree?

Comment: Pretty much. It's the developer's responsibility to make sure that the data is consistent. The framework provides entry points to different stages of the lifecycle and you should choose the best one for your case. Understanding the differences between each stage is essential. On a side note, any time consuming action like saving tons of data should be handled off the ui thread and in this case using `AsyncTask` is a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is just a guideline (and generally a good one). It is up to you exactly when you want to commit changes. I personally like to create Store Objects that allow a simplification of Databases or SharedPreferences, and when a change is made, I commit those changes immediately. For simple data storage, this will be quick and invisible to the user. For large data sets, this may take more time, and you may wish to make those writes on a time interval, as well as in onPause.

As for when to read - you can read whenever, but again longer reads will often affect the user experience, unless you have taken care of it in another thread, such as with an AsyncTask.

**To Further answer your update:**
It depends on the developer, however I would *write* in `onPause()` and if necessary, *read* in a separate thread, probably initialized with `onResume()`. I may also write data out on a scheduled interval using a `Timer` thread, depending on how it would affect the user experience for the current session, and if it would be catastrophic for the phone to turn off and lose all data before `onPause()` is called.

Comment: Thanks. You confirm my hunch. Rather than start a sequel question on the merit of both approaches, let me edit the question slightly.

Comment: @Calaf, please do create a new post. It is frowned upon to edit the question into a new one. Not only does it completely change the original question, but it also changes the original responses.

Comment: :) I made sure the update is distinct from the initial question. Your answer thus remains valid and pertinent. The update offers an example when one approach would be superior to the other.

Answer (score 0):

The true answer to this is, onPause is the only method you are guaranteed to get called before Android ***can*** destroy your process. If a user leaves your app to take a phone call, and Android decides to close your process, its entirely legal for you to only get an onPause call. If you hadn't saved your state there, when the user hits the back button, you will end up recreating your activity in a different state than the user left it in.

Comment: Your reasoning is perfectly in-line with Android's recommendation to write in onPause() rather than in onStop(). But it also directly contradicts the activity lifecycle graph (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). Would you, or anyone, care to elaborate?

Comment: Its not really: "If an activity is paused or stopped, the system can drop the activity from memory by either asking it to finish, or simply killing its process. When it is displayed again to the user, it must be completely restarted and restored to its previous state." If your process is killed, the remaining events will not be called. You will still be expected to resume to a user-friendly state when your process comes back up.

Comment: You are right indeed. Your quote indicates that an activity can be killed without first calling onStop(). (It is less clear whether onDestroy() can also be skipped.) If this is true, the graph is rather misleading.

Comment: onDestroy can be skipped as well. I'm 99% certain however, that the only way the graph is misleading is if the process is killed directly after onPause. In other words, the graph and life cycle are always followed unless Android has to kill your process because the memory pressure is that extreme.

Comment: Sorry for being finicky. What you are 99% sure about is that either Android would kill the process after onPause(), or it will let both on Stop() and onDestroy() get called. In other words, Android will not kill a process after onStop() but before onDestroy(). Is that right? (A reference or a justification why you believe this would be truly nice.)

Comment: The only guarantee (with the above quote as my reference) is that AT LEAST onPause() will be called before your process is killed. The truth is that once your process is killed, it really doesn't matter what you were going to do in onStop or onDestroy because everything you could have possibly been doing is getting killed by the system bringing down your process.

Comment: True, but then why is there a callback to onDestroy() at all? We might as well be doing everything in onPause() and onStop() and forget about onDestroy().

Comment: Because, your process is almost never killed just because the user left your activity. If the system has the memory to keep your Activity alive (or if you are just simply hitting the back button and going back to another activity in your app), you should use those callbacks to properly shut down any of the things you had previously kept running (no matter what reasoning you had).

Comment: I think they key thing you are missing in the quotes is that Android says it "can" drop your activity. When they say that they mean its a possibility, not a definite.

Comment: That's important. This sounds like the sort of rare scenario that would require extensive debugging if one had insufficient understanding of what was happening.